# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Rails51Point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jruby, jrubyonrails

This is my first time trying to upgrade an existing rails app. I am trying to update to rails 5.1.5 and when I start the server I get:

`Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Rails51Point`

This is a jruby app and here is the relevant portion of Gemfile:

`source 'https://rubygems.org' do
  gem 'rails', '5.1.5'
  gem 'haml'
  gem 'warbler'
  gem 'jruby-jars', '9.1.15.0'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', platform: :jruby
  gem 'activeresource'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.99', :group => :development
  gem 'listen'
  gem 'rake', '< 12.0'
  gem 'activerecord-session_store'
end`

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: From what version are you trying to upgrade?

Comment: Rails 3.2. It was suggested to me that I execute "rails new ..." on the app then adjust files and parameters accordingly as opposed to the gradual methods described here: [Rails Upgrade Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)

Comment: Oh, the suggestion was definitely bad. I think you should do it step by step: Go from 3.2 - 4.0 (fix all the errors and deprecation warnings), then go to 4.1, fix errors there, then go to 5.0 (fix errors and warnings), and from there you should be ok jumping to 5.1.5 (major versions can break stuff, so take your time)

Comment: Ok will make the case for step by step as it makes sense at this point.  Hopefully the issue won't appear at the end of that trail! Thanks.